# Maclaurin Series Representation for $f(z)=\frac{z}{z^4+9}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, taylor-expansion

I need help finding the Maclaurin series representation for $$f(z)=\frac{z}{z^4+9}$$

I first tried to factorize $z^4+9$, but am I missing something? I could not figure out how to factorize this. Is there another approach to this? I am open to any approach. Just help me figure this out through factorizing if possible.

Comment: Notice that $z^4 + 9 = (z^2 + 3i)(z^2 - 3i)$.

Answer (score 5):

**Hint 1:**
$$f(z)=\frac{z}{z^4+9}=\frac{1}{1+\left(\frac{z^4}{9}\right)}\cdot \frac{z}{9}$$

**Hint 2:**
$$\frac{1}{1-z}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty{z^n}$$

---

Using both hints,
$$\frac{1}{1+\left(\frac{z^4}{9}\right)}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty{\frac{(-1)^n}{3^{2n}}}z^{4n}\implies f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{3^{2n+2}}z^{4n+1}\,\,\, ,|z| < \sqrt{3}$$

Comment: Ok I see how you did this, but is there a way from factorizing?

Answer (score 0):

$$
\frac z {z^4+9} = \frac {z/9} {1 - (-z^4/9)} = \frac a {1-r} = a + ar + ar^2 + ar^3 + ar^4 + \cdots.
$$

Comment: I don't quite understand what you are doing here. Perhaps you can give some detail to your process?

Comment: @iamai : Generally if $|r|<1$ then $a + ar + ar^2 + ar^3+\cdots$ converges to $a/(1-r)$.  My first step was a bit of trivial algebra intended to rewrite $\dfrac z {z^4+9}$ in the form $\dfrac{\text{something}}{ 1 - \text{something}}$.  The thing in the numerator is then $z/9$, and I called that $a$.  The thing in the denominator is $1 - \left(\frac{-z^4} 9\right)$ and I called that $1-r$ so that $r=\dfrac{-z^4} 9$.  Then I have $\dfrac a {1-r}$, so I can expand that as the series $a+ar+ar^2+ar^3+\cdots$. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 0):

The geometric series $1-x+x^2-x^3+\cdots$ converges to $\frac{1}{x+1}$ for all $|x|<1$.

Substituting $x=\frac{y^4}{9}$ tells us that
$$1-\frac{1}{9}\,y^4 + \frac{1}{9^2} \, y^8 - \frac{1}{9^3}\, y^{12} + \cdots = \frac{1}{\frac{y^4}{9}+1} \equiv \frac{9}{y^4+9}$$
for all $\left|\frac{y^4}{9}\right|<1$, i.e. for all $|y| < \sqrt{3}$.

To get the power series we need, we just divide by $9$ and multiply by $y$:
$$\frac{1}{9}\,y-\frac{1}{9^2}\,y^5 + \frac{1}{9^3} \, y^9 - \frac{1}{9^4}\, y^{13} + \cdots = \frac{y}{y^4+9}$$
for all $|y| < \sqrt{3}$.